# ClientHandlerException when moving an envelope to recycle bin

Tags: java, rest, docusignapi

I'm currently trying to move an envelope to the recycle bin in order to delete it.

Here is my code :

```
public class DeleteEnvelopeTest {
    public static final String BaseUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";

    @Test
    public void shouldDeleteTheEnvelopeTest() {
        try {
            FoldersApi foldersApi = new FoldersApi();
            String envelopeId = "envelopeId";
            FoldersRequest foldersRequest = new FoldersRequest();
            foldersRequest.setEnvelopeIds(Arrays.asList(envelopeId));
            System.out.println(foldersApi.moveEnvelopes(accountId, "recyclebin", foldersRequest));
        } catch (ApiException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

When a execute this code, I have the following exception :

```
    GRAVE: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
    */* ->
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
      com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
    application/octet-stream ->
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
      com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider


    com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class com.docusign.esign.model.FoldersResponse, and Java type class com.docusign.esign.model.FoldersResponse, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found

        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:630)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:604)
        at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:606)
        at com.docusign.esign.api.FoldersApi.moveEnvelopes(FoldersApi.java:206)
        at com.orange.digisign.DeleteEnvelopeStatusTest.shouldDeleteTheEnvelopeTest(DeleteEnvelopeStatusTest.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

The strange thing here is that, when I go into my DocuSign account, I clearly see the envelope I want to delete into the recycle bin. Si, in this point of view, the test seems to work. But I always have this error. Do you have any idea where it can come from ?

I am not sure that it is an error of mines. The authentication process seems correct, as the envelope is moved and as it is the same I use to create and update an envelope.

Is it possible that DocuSign returns a bad formatted JSON ? Or that the return type is not the same for FoldersApi than for EnvelopesApi (it is the first time I use FoldersApi) ? I didn't see anything about it in the documentation, but I could have missed it.

Thanks,

EDIT : 
IN my log, I found this :

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net:7801/restapi/v2/accounts/2092727/folders/recyclebin

TraceToken: 48870a20-f9a8-445f-93ff-149c0d6e2c12
Timestamp: 2017-04-04T14:22:33.4101035Z

Content-Length: 56
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/2.0.2/java
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Password":"[omitted]","Username":"myEmail","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-DocuSign-SDK: Java
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 194.51.78.65

{"envelopeIds":["myEnvelopeId"]}
200 OK
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 48870a20-f9a8-445f-93ff-149c0d6e2c12
```

Do you need anything else ?

EDIT 2 : 
With more investigation, I found the follonwing results :

In the class ApiClient.java of DocuSign, the exception is throwing in the method invokeAPI, more precisely line 606. Here is the portion of corresponding portion of code :

```
public <T> T invokeAPI(String path, String method, List<Pair> queryParams, Object body, Map<String, String> headerParams, Map<String, Object> formParams, String accept, String contentType, String[] authNames, GenericType<T> returnType) throws ApiException {

    ClientResponse response = getAPIResponse(path, method, queryParams, body, headerParams, formParams, accept, contentType, authNames);

    statusCode = response.getStatusInfo().getStatusCode();
    responseHeaders = response.getHeaders();

     if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() == Family.SUCCESSFUL) {
      if (returnType == null)
        return null;
      else
        return response.getEntity(returnType);
    } 
}
```

It's the method "getEntity" who throws the exception, even if I see "class com.docusign.esign.mlodel.FoldersResponse" as field of "returnType".

Any help ?

EDIT 3 : I think, I found the solution, or at least the explanation. By executing some other tests.
I now obtain the following message :

```
com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: missing Content-Type in response
```

So, I guess, the problem is into DocuSign itself... Do you agree ?

Comment: Can you please enable your Request Logging on Docusign website and provide us the JSON you are sending. Instructions [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging)

Comment: It's possible the API request is succeeding but the SDK is not correctly parsing the response or otherwise failing on the client side.  Can you post the response you're receiving from the server?